# проход по выбранным элементам по селектору с конца JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Подскажите как можно сделать проход по выбранным элементам по селектору с конца?

если `each` с начала, то как с конца.

Comment: Чем Вас это не устраивает: [JQuery .each() backwards](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1394020/jquery-each-backwards)

Comment: @AntonKomyshan не находил такого. спасибо.

Comment: пожалуйста. Первая ссылка в гугле если что, и даже гугл подсказывает при вводе.